# ERROR al enlazar con JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

Error al mandar los datos al .jrxml.

La idea es desde una JTable leer los datos y pasarlos al reporte, todo sin conexion a base de datos.

Adjunto el error que lanza:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Corrige la ruta del archivo indicada en la variable `reporteSource`, indicando que se encuentra dentro de `Formularios`.

Comment: @A.Cedano  El problema era que no puede acceder a esa ruta, guardando el .jrxml en el escritorio si la acepta

Comment: Revisa si no es cuestión de permisos en esa ruta. Generalmente los formularios tienen que estar en la misma ruta de la aplicación, no en el escritorio o sueltos por ahí.